# Best SQL query results storage

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, hashtable

I'm storing results from a SQL query to an `Arraylist<Hashtable<String, String>>`, where each result is stored on an Hashtable and then each result is stored on a list

It works fine for if there are less than 100.000 results, buf if there are more results I get and OutOfMemory exception.

Do you hava any suggestions on how I can improove this situation?

Comment: Do you truly need all of the results at once? Odds are you can store a limited number and pull out more with another query when you actually need them. To do otherwise is generally just a waste of memory.

Comment: Yes I do, because what I'm doing is getting information from a JDBC database table and storing it in MongoDB, so I need to store all the information

Comment: I'm confused - why can't you do that as a multi-step process? If you're literally following SELECT queries with INSERT queries on another database, that's a perfect candidate for breaking it apart. Regardless, you'll inevitably have to do something like this unless the JDBC database table will never grow. Even if you can make your storage marginally more efficient, strings are big. You will run out of memory eventually.

Comment: Can you do this in the WHILE loop reading records from the recordset one by one and saving to MongoDB inside that loop?

Comment: You are completelly right Chris. I didn't think about that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably save some space by using a custom class to represent each row.  (A `HashMap` is a rather "memory hungry" data structure.)  However, that is only going to put off the inevitable OOME.

A better idea would be to change you application so that you don't have to store the entire resultset in memory at all.

Comment: A custom class isn't an option because I don't know the result columns of each table. There are loads and loads of tables.

Comment: But presumably the tables represent the business objects. You could have one class per table. Admittedly there could be a great many classes, but the code would be more maintainable.

Comment: If custom classes are not an option, then `HashMap` is your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different approaches. Stechen C is correct, it would be best to use a 'where' clause in your SQL to reduce the size of your result set.

If you are using caching, you can set a maximum size for the cache, and the best class for that is LinkedHashMap. There is an implementation of Map which keeps the insertion order. You'll need to subclass it and override the removeEldestEntry() method, as indicated in the Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and probably least memory intensive way to improve this is to keep a two-dimensional array for your data:

```
String[][] data;

// Alternatively, if you prefer lists:
List<String[]> data;
```

You would then need just one additional data structure, such as

```
Map<String, Integer> fieldNameToIndexMapping;
```

... where you'd store a lookup table to access your fields by column index. E.g.

```
String value = data[row][fieldNameToIndexMapping.get("MY_COLUMN")];
```

More tuning is possible by using more concise data types, where appropriate. I suspec that some of the `String` values that you're storing in your data structure are actually `Boolean`, `Integer` and other items that would be easier to store in a non-string form.